# Lorentzian module

Tags: python, python-2.7, curve-fitting

So I am using this lorenzian fit to my code, but something is not right with my code.

```
x = freqs2
y = psd2

model = LorentzianModel()
model.guess(y, x=x)
#model.param_names['amplitude'].value = int(6)

init_fit = model.model(x=x)
model.fit(y, x=x)

final_fit = model.model(x=x)

plt.plot(x, final_fit, 'r-')
plt.plot(x, init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, y,         'bo')
```

I got error that there is no attribute called "model", do You have any idea what to do? I am using documentation. When I comment those lines with model I get this:

[image]

Which is almost what I need, but what do to with this attribute error?

BTW.

```
#model.param_names['amplitude'].value = int(6)
```

This line also is not working, so I commented it.

EDIT:

```
x = freqs2
y = psd2

mod = LorentzianModel()

pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)
out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))
```

I've checked my code for that, and it seems giving good results, but I have no idea how to plot it. I am using this from this side:

```
https://lmfit-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peaked-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles
```

Comment: Can you share a snap-shot of the error you're getting?

Comment: `no attribute called model` it is written in my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **always better** to post actual code that runs to show the problem *and* to show the full result, including any error messages.  Really, always better, never worse.  Say what you did (ie, post full code) and what happened (ie, post full output).  It's alarming how many people don't do this and incorrectly assume that people will want to help them with a woefully incomplete question ("I did something, but it didn't work. Help pleeze!").  The good news is that now you, yes you, Tommy, know this and never have to be that sort of person ever again.

There are a few different problems with your code, besides being incomplete.  I encourage you to look at the examples in the documentation, such as at https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peak-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles and the many examples at https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/tree/master/examples

It seems you're fairly new to python.  Otherwise, you would have run the above code (assuming imports had happened correctly and data defined) and seen

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfit.py", line XXX, in <module>
    init_fit = model.model(x=x)
AttributeError: 'LorentzianModel' object has no attribute 'model'
```

and realized that `model` does not have an attribute called `model`.

You might be looking for a way to evaluate the model. You didn't explicitly ask this (hint: next time ASK A QUESTION YOU WANT ANSWERED!), but if you did you might have read the documentation to find the method `eval()`
(http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#lmfit.model.Model.eval).  This needs a `params` object, holding the parameters.  You could have obtained this from `model.guess()`, but you didn't keep the value returned from `model.guess()` so you don't have that to pass to `model.eval()`.  Doing something like:

```
model = LorentzianModel()
params = model.guess(y, x=x)
init_fit = model.eval(params, x=x)
```

would have worked, and then you could (for example) plot the data and initial fit.  You could proceed with an actual fit, but you would need to include the parameters again, doing at least

```
model.fit(y, params, x=x) # don't do this!
```

for the fit to happen. Of course, you'd almost certainly want to know what the results of that fit were, so, you'd need to save the result, which would require

```
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x) # yes, do this!
```

To see the best fit though after the fit, you would not do

```
final_fit = model.eval(params, x=x) # no, that is still the initial fit!!
```

but rather do

```
final_fit = model.eval(result.params, x=x) # yes, this uses the resulting parameters
```

or even better

```
final_fit = result.best_fit  # the best fit is already included in the result
```

BTW, your commented-out line

```
model.param_names['amplitude'].value = int(6)
```

was not working because `model.param_names` is a list, not a dict.  But this isn't what you want anyway.  Assuming you are intending to set an initial value for the `amplitude` parameter to `6`, you would do

```
model = LorentzianModel()
params = model.guess(y, x=x)
params['amplitude'].value = 6  # no need for int()!
```

If you don't want to start with "guessed" parameter values, you could also make a parameters object giving initial values for all variable parameters, like

```
model = LorentzianModel()
params = model.make_params(amplitude=6, center=5, sigma=1)
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Well that post was kinda passive agressive, but I understand what's Your point. Thanks for the tips and advice for the future :) Thank You